# constantly run python script

Tags: php, python, cgi

I have a python script that texts me when something changes on a website. How can I put this on a server so that it is checking 24/7 without me having to keep my laptop open? Any tutorials or documentation would be good.

I have searched for ways to do this everywhere, but can't really find much. I see that php could be used to do it, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a cron job. "Cron" is a time based job scheduler.

Ex:

```
11 2 * * * /path/to/bin/python /path/to/cronjobs/sent_text.py
```

This Cron will run once an hour on the hour

Here is a [Cron Job Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Comment: but where does it run on. does cron have a server

Comment: Its on the server already.  What kind server are you using? In the tutorial you can read the section titled 'Setting Up and Managing Cron Jobs'

Comment: ok so basically my question is how do I run a script on a server? i can figure out cron after

Comment: Cron Job will run your script for you.  I'll update a cron example to show one of my Crontabs that runs a python script.

Comment: yea it'll run with my laptop open but what is a server I can put it on?

Comment: This type will run on a unix type server.  (Linux, Ubuntu)  I like webfaction (https://www.webfaction.com/?aid=70681), but there are many choices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85391/discussion-between-matthew-and-rishubk).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your python script as a daemon. That is detach it from the controlling terminal. You can easily wrap it in a shell script like the one given below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script_file=$(readlink -f "$0")  #absolute path to this file
python_file=$(readlink -f "$1")  #absolute path to the python script
output_file=$([[ "$2" == "" ]] && echo "/dev/null" || readlink -f "$2")  #absolute path to the output file

(
    exec 0>&- 0>/dev/null #close and redirect stdin
    exec 1>&- 1>>"${output_file}" #close and redirect stdout
    exec 2>&- 2>>"${output_file}" #close and redirect stderr
    python "$python_file" 
    "$script_file" "$python_file" "$output_file"
) &
```

Save this script as `script.sh` and give it executable permission, i.e `chmod +x script.sh` Now executing `script.sh <python script> <output file>` will start the python script with stdout and stderr redirected to the output file given. It will also restart the python script if it is terminated.